# Modx rich text input field for template variable

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates

I'm new to modx Rev and I am trying to set the input field for a template variable so that it uses my chosen richtext editor. If I set the input field as rich text I just get a 1 line text field. If I set the editor as Textarea then thats all I get a text area field - there is no option in the drop down under input options for "html" as some tutorials suggest. Have I not enabled something? I am a bit lost being new to the app.

Comment: So, what type of input are you trying to capture? HTML or rich text?

Comment: I'm trying to capture html but there is no "html" option on the drop down for Input Type - the only relevant options seem to be text area or rich text. I am using the latest version of Modx

Comment: You don't want a rich text editor, you want a code editor then - like ACE or code mirror. [please update your question] 
Not sure about ACE or code mirror, but Markitup has some system settings for individual rich text fields. It's not well documented. but might be a start

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am using ACE and I have tried Codemirror. When I set the input type for the variable there is no "code" option. The tutorials I have looked up all mention using a "richtext editor". When I enable either codemirror or ace I do not get to use it for any of my template variables no matter what field type I choose even though the editor is enabled in system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. My solution

1. Go to Package Management and search for TinyMCE.
2. Download it. Then click Install.
3. Set the Input for my Template Variable to RichText
4. Click on Resource then Template Variables and now I see the TinyMCE editor

Answer (score 0):

Which rich text editor have you installed?

Is **Rich Text** enabled for the resource you are editing, if not then I think a different editor will be used.

Comment: I'm currently using Ace though I did also try codemirror. I cannot get ACE to work at all - code mirror works for page content but does not enable for TV when set to either rich text or textarea. The only enabling of richtext editor I have done is through system/system settings and then use_editor: yes, which_editor: Ace, which_element_editor: Ace

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading TinyMCE instead through package management, and use that one instead. Might wanna uninstall ACE to make sure it doesn't interfere somewhere.